# Overriding "Text" property derived from System::Windows::Forms::Control C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, controls, overriding

I'm trying to override "Text" property in base class i've searched to anywhere before but it doesn't make any change, and i'm still confused how can i put the code correctly, of course in header file and CPP file.

```
public ref class MyCustomControl:  public System::Windows::Forms::Control
{
     [Overriding "Text" property goes here...]

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
public ref class MyCustomControl:  public System::Windows::Forms::Control
{
    virtual property System::String^ Text
    {
        System::String^ get() override { return L"Blahblah"; }
        void set(System::String^ value) override { /*...*/ }
    }
};
```